# Update query is working in mysql but not in netbeans

Tags: java, mysql, sql, netbeans

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
String hostip = hmodify.getText();
String source = sdmodify.getText();
String target = tdmodify.getText();
String login =  lnmodify.getText();
String password = String.valueOf(pmodify.getPassword());
String scheduledOn = somodify.getText();
String scheduledAt = samodify.getText();
    Connection conn = null;
    conn = MySqlConnect1.ConnectDB();
    PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
    try {
        String sql = "update host set target_dir=?, source_dir=?, login_name=?, password=?, backup_schedule=?, backup_time=? where host=?";
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        pstmt.setString(1, hostip);
        pstmt.setString(2, source);
        pstmt.setString(3, target);
        pstmt.setString(4, login);
        pstmt.setString(5, password);
        pstmt.setString(6, scheduledOn);
        pstmt.setString(7, scheduledAt);
        int i = pstmt.executeUpdate();
        if(i>0)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Data is Saved");
        }
        else
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Data is Not Saved");
        }


    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
}
```

Update query is working perfectly in mysql but not in netbeans. No error is shown but still not updating the table. May be there is some problem with the where clause. Please help me to get through it.

Comment: Seems to me like the order of the parameters is wrong. Should hostip parameter be the last one ?

Answer (score 0):

i think you are giving values in wrong locations. Explained below

Your query is

```
    String sql = "update host set target_dir=?, source_dir=?, 
login_name=?, password=?, backup_schedule=?, backup_time=? where host=?";
```

Assume host ip is "192.168.10.10" and when following statement execute 
 `pstmt.setString(1, hostip);` you query will become

```
    update host set target_dir="192.168.10.10", source_dir=?,
 login_name=?, password=?, backup_schedule=?, backup_time=? where host=?;
```

So please make sure that number corresponding to value is in proper order in your  pstmt.setString statments

Answer (score 0):

You have set wrong sequence for all columns, please try this (especially for `hostip` which is actually your `where` clause)

```
    pstmt.setString(1, target);
    pstmt.setString(2, source);
    pstmt.setString(3, login);
    pstmt.setString(4, password);
    pstmt.setString(5, scheduledOn);
    pstmt.setString(6, scheduledAt);
    pstmt.setString(7, hostip);
```